# AttributeError: Message instance has no attribute 'pack'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter for the GUI, and I have one problem:
I try to make a message widget, and when I write:

```
body = Message(top, bd = 2)
body.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

I get this error:

```
body.pack(side=RIGHT)
AttributeError: Message instance has no attribute 'pack'
```

I dont understand this becaue I checked in some guides and Its allowed to use 'message' this way, as seen here in the example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_message.htm

Is there another way to write this?

Comment: It's possible you either have a different version of Tkinter, or you've imported something else into your namespace with the name Message.  What do your import statement(s) look like?

Comment: Thank for the fast response. Here is how my import statement looks like: 
    from socket import *
    from base64 import *
    from Tkinter import *
    from tkMessageBox import *

Comment: I dont know how to organize codes in comments, Im new here, sorry..

Comment: `from ... import *` is generally a bad idea as it makes it very hard to tell what things are in your code. Try doing `print(Message)` and see where the class has come from.

Comment: this is what I get when I write print(message): <tkMessageBox.Message instance at 0x01EB8AF8>

Comment: The tutorial you're using appears to have been written when Python 2.5 was around. Nowadays Python uses tk 8.5. In earlier versions there apparently was a geometry manager called the Packer, there's no references to it in the copies of the 8.4 and 8.5 Tkinter reference guides I have. See [Tkinter 8.5 reference a GUI for Python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/). See if you can find a more up-to-date tutorial or book.

Comment: @martineau: there has always been a geometry manager named `pack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two `Message` classes in Tkinter. One of them comes from `tkMessageBox.Message`, and the other one is from `Tkinter.Message`. The former is a subclass of the `Dialog` from `tkCommonDialog`, and since packing a dialog is meaningless, there is no `pack` method for this case. The later is a Tk widget called message, which is the one you want; being a widget, it makes sense to pack it.

Your complete code mostly like have something in the form (Python 2):

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
```

The second import shadows the `Message` class from the first import. To use the `Message` class you are after, simply change the above code to:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
```

Then adapt your code accordingly.

Comment: Even better advice IMO is to advocate non-global imports, such as `import Tkinter as tk`

Comment: Thanks that help but it seems to be there is another problem? Aren't meesage supposed to be multiline input? because its just a text box with a text I wrote in the code. I cant write in this box..

Comment: It is a multiline label, the opposite of an input widget.